# Enable text selection on disabled inputs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a large form with many input elements which need to be non-editable until a user clicks a button, but need to allow text selection for copying values to other forms.

My existing solution was to wrap the inputs in a disabled fieldset, which worked until the most recent Chrome release which doesn't allow text selection on disabled inputs.

Other questions here have had the readonly attribute suggested, but it isn't supported for fieldsets, so it doesn't cascade to child elements (see code snippet).

Any suggestions, or will I be stuck adding readonly to every input element? I'm also using AngularJS, so if there is an angular solution that may work as well.

EDIT: I should note that I've considered using ngReadonly (currently using ngDisabled on the fieldset) but ngReadonly doesn't work on fieldsets, and would have to be added to several hundred inputs across my application.

```
<html>
<body>
  <fieldset disabled>
    <input value="I am disabled by my parent" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset readonly>
    <input value="I am readonly" readonly/>
    <input value="I am not readonly, despite my parent" />
  </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and if you create a policy that covers all children of the element and added the readonly property

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this would suffice..

This might not be very *angular-thinking*, but it will allow you to keep the existing structure.

```js
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("fieldset[readonly]")).children('input').attr('readonly','readonly');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <fieldset disabled>
    <input value="I am disabled by my parent" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset readonly>
    <input value="I am readonly" readonly/>
    <input value="I am not readonly, despite my parent" />
  </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using AngularJS, you could think of something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <fieldset disabled>
    <input value="I am disabled by my parent" />
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <input value="I am readonly" {{Shold_Be_Readonly_or_Not}}/>
    ...
  </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

and within the controller, set `$scope.Shold_Be_Readonly_or_Not` as either `readonly` or an empty string.

Comment: Angular has ngReadonly which essentially does this. I'd like to avoid having to us it though, since that would need to be added to several hundred inputs across my application.

Comment: @AdamAxtmann, of course, I forgot about ngReadonly. Whatever solution you find, it will anyway require you to (at least) visit all your several hundreds input fields (either just to check the logic is OK or to do some small changes).